# Are those log files in /storage/sdcard0/log necessary?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sd-card, files, logging

On my SGS2 (GT-I9100, Android 4.1.2), 1.2GB of log files piled up in the folder

```
/storage/sdcard0/log
```

. I have almost no space left on the internal SD card and a lot of the space is used by those log files, so I want to get rid of them once and for all.

To give you an idea what's there, here are two examples of file names stored there:

```
dmesg_cp_boot_201405280100_24.log
logcat_cp_boot_radio_20140219173_53.log
```

Is it normal that those logfiles get saved there? I can simply delete them, but then new ones are written there anyways. Can I prevent that?

**UPDATE**:

The logfiles seem to have started appearing about a year ago. The file with the oldest date in the file name is `logcat_cp_boot_radio_201304060741_36.log`.

Most of the files have names of the form `logcat_cp_boot_radio_*.log`, but some are also called `dmesg_cp_boot_*.log` or `dmesg_cp_boot_done_*.log`, the latter two being completely empty files (0 bytes length).

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: @Chahk, I had rooted it once, but afaik I've unrooted it afterwards. I've done this a long time ago (2 years?), so I don't remember exactly. Can I do something to check this so I can give you a definitive answer?

Comment: Try opening up Terminal Emulator and issuing `su` command.  If that succeeds or pops up a dialogue asking for permission - you are rooted.  Regardless, try the following: open the dialer and enter `*#9900#`. This should open the SysDump utility. Now tap on the `Delete dumpstate/logcat` button.

Comment: @Chahk, $ su => /system/bin/sh: su: not found

Comment: Not rooted then. The SysDump should work regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the presence of `logcat_cp_boot_radio*.log` files point to an issue with the phone's modem.  It's possible that when you first rooted the device you flashed a ROM which contained a modem firmware that was either old, or slightly incompatible with your current carrier.  Besides amassing large amounts of these log files, you would see frequent disconnects and reconnects from cell and data services when the radio crashes and restarts.

While you can always keep [deleting the log files](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2013/11/01/galaxy-s2-clearing-logs-on-an-unrooted-phone/) every now and then to free up the memory, the larger issue will persist. In order to resolve the root cause of the RIL crash, you will need to install the proper radio firmware.  These differ based on geographic location, and sometimes on the carrier.

The first step is to find the modem version that is currently installed on your phone.  You can find this information in Settings -> About phone, under the "Baseband version." It should start with "i19100", and then followed by some letters and numbers.  The letters represent a geographic location:

> CE---> Belgium, Luxembourg, Netherlands
>   DC---> Thailand
>   DD---> India
>   DX---> Indonesia, Malaysia, Philippines, Singapore, Vietnam
>   DZ---> Malaysia, Singapore
>   JA---> South Africa
>   JC---> Algeria, Morocco, Nigeria, South Africa, Tunisia
>   JP---> Arabic, Algeria, Egypt, Iran, Iraq, Kuwait, Morocco, Nigeria,
>   Oman, Pakistan, Saudi Arabia, Syria
>   JV---> Tunisia, Turkey
>   UG---> North America
>   UH---> Latin America, The Caribbean
>   XE---> Bulgaria, Estonia, Kazakhstan, Latvia, Lithuania, Russia,
>   Ukraine
>   XX---> Austria, Belgium, France, Germany, Hungary, United Kingdom
>   XW---> Austria, Belgium, France, Germany, Hungary, Italy, Nordic,
>   Spain, United Kingdom
>   ZC---> China, Hong Kong
>   ZH---> Hong Kong
>   ZS---> China, Hong Kong
>   ZT---> Taiwan

And the numbers represent the version, incremented alphabetically.  You should find the latest modem version based on the country you are in, and then flash it on your phone using either Odin, or Recovery (must be a custom recovery like ClockworkMod or TWRP, for example.)

A quick Google search yielded [this site](http://veyka.co.uk/sgs2/radios/) which contains ClockworkMod-formatted modems for the Galaxy S2 I9100 variant for various countries.  I'm not sure how recent it is, but this should start you off in the right direction.